# is it possible to make a NSTextView autoscroll down to the last line in swift xcode

Tags: swift

i'm trying to make it so that every time i press enter in a textfield

it makes a NSTextView automaticly scroll down to the last line in the scrollview

```
let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.characters.count - 1, 0)
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

i tried all sort of ways but it never scroll down the text in the NSTextView

Comment: Note that `NSTextView` has no `text` property

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? Note that `characters` property is deprecated in Swift4. You should update your Xcode to the latest version from the AppStore 9.1

Comment: Do you want it to scroll down only when "enter" key is pressed or would you like to scroll down when "return" or "enter" is pressed. Also do you want it to add a new line when it is pressed or not? Note that the cursor might not be in the end of the text.

Comment: i'd like it to scroll down when i run a certain function that adds lines to the textview

Comment: i have the latiest version of xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `addLocalMonitorForEvents` for `.keyDown` events to your view controller and check if the `event.keyCode == 76`.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textview: NSTextView!
    var keyDown: Any!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        keyDown = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
            self.keyDown(with: $0)
            return $0
        }
    }
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if event.keyCode == 76 {
            print("enter key pressed")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textview.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: self.textview.string.count, length: 0))
            }
        }
    }
    deinit {
        NSEvent.removeMonitor(keyDown)
    }
}
```

---

If you just need to scroll it down after your method adds lines to the textview just add this to the end of it:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.textview.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: self.textview.string.count, length: 0))
}
```

Comment: its telling me Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'textView'

Comment: its connected i can put text in it without any problem but when i put that line in that it tells me what i pasted

Comment: just to be sure i connected the 2 the things i could connect that are part of the textview and both of them gave me the same error

Comment: i just checked and yes that is exactly the one i got linked and that im referencing

Comment: not its saying that 'ViewController' has no member 'textView'

Comment: @jana_lemmings just use `textview` instead of `textView` it is case sensitive. check my edit

Comment: yeah i had forgoten to adjust the second textview reference thats why i didnt tought the reference was wrong